# AccessibilityService - Perform ACTION_CLICK on unclickable item

Tags: java, android, accessibilityservice

I have tried to perform ACTION_CLICK on clickable item successfully. But, It's not working with unclickable item. Here my code:

```
List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> nodeInfoList = rootNode.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.VCB:id/tvLanguage");
            if (nodeInfoList == null || nodeInfoList.isEmpty())
                return;

            for (AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo : nodeInfoList) {
                nodeInfo.setVisibleToUser(false);
                nodeInfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text:" + nodeInfo.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Android widget TextView of "com.VCB:id/tvLanguage":

```
<android.widget.TextView index="1" package="com.VCB" class="android.widget.TextView" text="English" resource-id="com.VCB:id/tvLanguage" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[894,206][1019,252]" displayed="true" />
```

As you can see, the clickable="false", which not allow me to click it by AccessibilityService. Is there any approach to bypass this?

Thank you,

Comment: If it's not clickable for a normal user, why would it be clickable for a TalkBack user?

Comment: Hi, I can click it with normal use. But I can't use AccessibilityService to perform the ACTION_CLICK on it

Comment: Not sure how you can click it when the xml sets the textview with `clickable="false"`

Comment: Yes, I have the same concern as you. I dont know why I can click on it, but the clickable="false". I only notice when using AccessibilityService. It's not clickable for AccessibilityService

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have found the answer but maybe you could try this:

```
nodeInfo.getParent().performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
```

If you have your button inside a list or some place, maybe this could help you.

If that, does not work, check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo#setVisibleToUser(boolean)) because it says that you can't call the `setVisibleToUser()` method from an AccessibilityService.